# Can't get a node stream's finish event to fire

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to determine when a node WriteStream is done writing:

```
var gfs = GFS(db);

var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream(
{
    filename: "thismyfile.txt",
    root: "myfiles"
});

writeStream.on("finish", function()
{
    console.log("finished");
    response.send({ Success: true });
});

writeStream.write("this might work");
writeStream.end();

console.log("end");
```

In my console, I see "end", but never "finished", and there is never a response. The stream is writing properly, however, and it seems to be finishing (I see the completed file in the database). That even just isn't firing. I've tried moving the "this might work" into the call to end() and removing write(), I've also tried passing a string into end() as well. That string is written to the stream, but still no callback.

Why might this event not be getting fired?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Node are you using and what is `GFS`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured out the issue. GFS is gridfs-stream, which doesn't actually have a "finish" event. Only a "close" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gridfs-stream` module is designed and written primarily for node `0.8.x` and below and does not use the `stream2`-style methods provided by `require('stream').WritableStream` in node >= `0.10.x`. Because of this, it does not get the standardized `finish` event. It is up to the module implementation itself to emit `finish`, which it apparently does not.